# Getting StopIteration error in read_csv() python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, parsing, dataframe, append

I have a data frame called `summaryDF` like this (titles amended for MCVE):

```
         f1         precision recall  threshold
A        0.600321   0.739130  0.111   0.001
B        0.096692   0.826087  0.2321  0.001
C        0.072539   0.875000  0.4531  0.001
D        0.128079   0.722222  0.2311  0.001
```

I am then running a batch script which runs a machine learning pipeline of 3 `.py` files with a different `threshold` hyperparameter and at the end of the third file, I want to append the precision, F1 and recall results to the bottom of the file. So for example, the next iteration should make the file look like:

```
         f1         precision recall  threshold
A        0.600321   0.739130  0.111   0.001
B        0.096692   0.826087  0.2321  0.001
C        0.072539   0.875000  0.4531  0.001
D        0.128079   0.722222  0.2311  0.001
A        0.121211   0.312214  0.3213  0.005
B        0.214422   0.432332  0.2311  0.005
C        0.081111   0.121211  0.1322  0.005
D        0.012121   0.212444  0.6546  0.005
```

This is my current code:

```
with open(data/output/test/summaryEval.csv, 'w+') as summaryCSV:
    try:
        df_csv = pd.read_csv(summaryCSV,encoding='utf-8',engine='python')
    except ValueError as v:
        print v
        summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=summaryCSV, encoding='utf-8')
        summaryCSV.close()
    else:
        summaryDF = pd.concat([df_csv,summaryDF],axis=1)
        summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=summaryCSV,encoding='utf-8',mode='a')
        summaryCSV.close()
```

What is going wrong? Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/logisticBagOfWords.py", line 477, in <module>
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(summaryCSV,encoding='utf-8',engine='python')
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 250, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 566, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 711, in _make_engine
    self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1429, in __init__
    self.columns, self.num_original_columns = self._infer_columns()
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1644, in _infer_columns
    line = self._buffered_line()
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1771, in _buffered_line
    return self._next_line()
  File "/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1802, in _next_line
    orig_line = next(self.data)
StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was opening a file in the same mode whether there is a file or not vs. there being information in the file already. Hence I open in different modes according to these cases.

```
    try:
        if os.stat(sys.argv[5]).st_size > 0:
            with open(sys.argv[5], 'a') as f:
                summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f,encoding='utf-8',mode='a',header=False)
                f.close()
        else:
            print "empty file"
            with open(sys.argv[5], 'w+') as f:
                summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f,encoding='utf-8')
                f.close()
    except OSError:
        print "No file"
        with open(sys.argv[5], 'w+') as f:
            summaryDF.to_csv(path_or_buf=f,encoding='utf-8')
            f.close()
```